# Free Credit Card Java API available

Tags: java

I am looking for a free java api that allows the data read off a credit card to be processed and validated.  I'm NOT looking for a payment gateway to do that.  I basically want to read the card, store the components in memory and know it's a valid card.

Is there any java libraries out there that are free that can do this?

Currently I have a USB card reader, and visually I can "pick out" most of the pieces but i'm sure there is checksum data and I know the CCV1 data in here somewhere, but where/how I don't know and would prefer to use an API instead of reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't check to see if a card is truly "valid" without going through a payment processor.  You can verify the card number by computing the checksum (algorithm easily locatable via google, and extremely simple to implement), but you can't even verify the CVV/CVS number yourself - that's a hash that only the card processing network knows.  (Not even the bank knows that number, at least not directly.)

Comment: +1. You can check for correctness -- that is, whether a card number _could_ correspond to a valid card. But you can't check for validity without going to the network. This is a good thing -- if there were somehow an offline way to do this, card security would be greatly compromised, because everyone would know which card numbers were valid!

Comment: Indeed, that is the point of CVV: in lieu of a signature, it is meant to be a piece of information that only the card holder will know.

Comment: Ok, so foregoing the above is there any libraries available for at least translating the raw data into something more "usable" ?